# Loading Two Arrays in One Drop-Down List For Option Value and Text

Tags: php, arrays

Can you please let me know how to load two arrays in one drop down list one for value (**$values**) and the other array (**$colors**) for text.

```
<?php 
$colors = array("Red", "Green", "Blue", "Tellow"); 
$values = array("#444444", "#ff0055", "#bb0055", "#bb4455");

?> 

<select name="color-list">
<?php 
    foreach($colors as $colorslist) 
    {
       echo '<option value="">'.$colorslist.'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Combine` the two array and then loop it

```
$colors = array("Red", "Green", "Blue", "Tellow"); 
$values = array("#444444", "#ff0055", "#bb0055", "#bb4455");
$combined = array_combine($values, $colors);

<select name="color-list">
<?php 
    foreach($combined as $key=>$value) 
    {
       echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Your so Reputation addicted! It's incredible... You command almost OP to accept your answer. sad sad

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple logic:

```
<?php 

$colors = array("Red", "Green", "Blue", "Tellow"); 
$values = array("#444444", "#ff0055", "#bb0055", "#bb4455");

?> 

<select name="color-list">

<?php 
    foreach($colors as $key => $color) 
    {
       echo '<option value="'.$color.'">'.$values[$key].'</option>';
    }
?>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($colors as $idx => $colorslist)
{
    echo '<option value="' . $values[$idx] . '">'.$colorslist.'</option>';
}
```

you can access data from $values array over index of current element $colors array

Comment: Please add a description.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you combine the two arrays in one as keys and values

```
$color-list = array("Red"=>"#444444", "Green"=>"#ff0055");
foreach($color-list as $k => $v){
echo "<option value='{$k}'>" . $v . "</option>";
```

}